Webots to epuck2 bluetooth remote control - unclear documentation / getting started
been looking at using the epuck2 with webots for educational purposes and I hit a snag.
Windows 11, Webots r2023b, epuck2 (latest firmware manually updated)
Bluetooth connection to the epuck2 works as per a manual terminal connection and my own python progams.
Simulation with epuck in webots works seamlessly.
According to webots documentation (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/epuck?version=R2021a#bluetooth-remote-control, slightly older version) it says that I need to open the robot window and use that to install the hex file on the robot before remote control will work.

instructions do not specify which com port. The epuck2 spawns 6 COM ports for different purposes. Manually trying each of them gives me no success and no feedback.
the comports listed all have a "." in front of them (i.e., ".COM4" instead of "COM4"). Connecting to any of the com ports right away says access denied.

Any thoughts or ideas? Can anyone point me to updated documentation perhaps? I thought that windows used to put dots in front of high com ports, but my other programs/apps don't need it.
Thanks!
